# Local transparent proxy

Tags: debian, proxy, squid, http-proxy

In my workplace I'm using Debian Linux. It is, however, a Windows shop and recently they decided to install a proxy that needs my Windows domain credentials to use.

I can only access the Internet through it, and I find extremely annoying the need to configure every program to use it. Worse, when I arrive home and use the computer, I have to change again the configuration for each program that needs Internet access.

I know that a transparent proxy could help me (along some iptables configuration), but I need one that is able to relay my http / https traffic to another proxy to which it should authenticate with my domain credentials.

Also I would like to have a easy way to disable this configuration when I return home and be able to activate it again next day. If possible I would like something light on resources.

I think squid is able to do this, but it seems overkill for a local installation.

What is the best way to solve this? Some sample configuration could help too....

Answer (score 0):

-Friend, listen you might not want to be doing this by having to purchase one, but believe it would be better for you "as so avoid major problems" have a well-configured router, so you could accomplish this you want and still have a better control traffic as there are great options available routers on the market, take a look out there know you will enjoy some ...